# Drupal 7 DraggableViews order

Tags: drupal, view, draggable

```
I have 2 separate views for the image gallery having categorize using term. 
One for admin(draggable) and second for anonymous user. Admin can change 
order(weight) of the gallery.
I am using this weight in second views but this is not working properly

Even i have added SORT CRITERIA on **Draggableviews: Weight (asc)** in 
both views.
```

Is there any way to add as a field weight so that i can debug this issue or any other solution

Answer (score 3):

Only solution that worked for me was the following:

- go to your content type/vocabulary
- add a weight field (label: weight | machine name: weight | field type: integer
- edit your sorting view and add sort criteria for your newly added weight field
- edit your draggable views field and change "Handler" from Native to FieldAPI
- under Field select your weight field
- go to your content view and add the new weight field as you sort criteria

This is the only thing that worked for me. If it doesn't work immediately, just reorder a few items on your draggable view so that the ordering values are reset.

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The draggableviews module doesn't use the weight field for sorting. If you have followed the instructions for using the draggableviews module you should have two views, 1 for sorting with the draggable items and 1 for displaying the sorted view. It is important that on both your views you should have the 'DraggableViews: Order' as the FIRST sort criteria.

> As a final extra step, you'll go back to your regular page display for the view and add "DraggableViews: Order" at the Sort criteria section and place it as the first Sort criteria. For sorting order, choose "Ascending".
>   https://drupal.org/node/283498

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Taxonomy term view which is already exist in drupal 7 views. It is not working for this view...

Comment: If you are using the taxonomy term view, make sure that the format setting for the display you want is using the table format. Follow the instructions for using the draggableviews module and it will sort the result accordingly.